# Sharepoint 2019 communication site does not switch to arabic layout when Arabic language is selected in mysite

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, language-pack

I created a site in English and added Arabic as alternate language in Sharepoint Server 2019. I enabled it in the language settings.
[image]

The user has selected the language in Arabic in the language preferences.

[image]

However, still the site is shown in english language.

[image]

Need some help on how to make the page display in Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the primary language once it is set. Having the user set their language in the profile as you are doing is the right way to do it. Make sure you scroll down and press the save button.  It takes several minutes for the language change to apply. For that particular site template it should switch to right to left layout as soon as the language applies.  Press Ctrl-F5 every couple of minutes to check.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your site default language is English. Though an alternate language have been added, the site will display default language unless the user who is logged in has chosen the same alternate language in their **User Profile**. Besides, make sure to make alternate language primary language.

Comment: How to change the site in primary language as Arabic?